# How do I retain command history for psql running within PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, psql, command-line

I'm running the following version of psql

psql (12.11)

on Windows Powershell running on Windows 10.  Within the same shell session, when I log in and out of psql, it doesn't retain the previous commands (e.g. SELECT statements) that I ran in a previous session.  What do I need to do in order for psql to retain its history, even if only during the same Windows PowerShell session?

Comment: I think this is simply not supported on Windows.

Comment: I guess you could try building your own, using [the Windows port of the readline library](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/readline.htm).

Comment: Check to see if an 'up arrow' will retrieve last line requested in Windows Powershell, please and let us know.